# Programmatically enable/disable accessibility settings on Android

Tags: java, android, layout

How can I programmatically enable/disable an android screen reader service such as **TalkBack**?

I am developing an app to help people get more accessibility, I want to be able to change android settings right from the app like talk back, screen color, enable bold text on phone and so on.

Or if there is no way to do that, at least open the exact location that could be modified.

The discussion at the link below has many suggesting launching **Android's Settings** app. But there's nothing about it these days, not working as well.

**Question:**

How to programmatically enable/disable accessibility service in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this programmatically. A business reason for this is that Google wants to sell its Cloud Speech-to-Text service.

From [AccessibilityService DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService):

> The lifecycle of an accessibility service is managed exclusively by
> the system and follows the established service life cycle. Starting an
> accessibility service is triggered exclusively by the user explicitly
> turning the service on in device settings.
>
> An accessibility service stops either when the user turns it off in
> device settings or when it calls `AccessibilityService#disableSelf()`.